# Parsing XML from SOAP response with jQuery

Tags: jquery, parsing, soap

I have problems parsing response from SOAP server with jQuery.

this is request

```
POST /REMEDIFINDERSERVICES/HSWebService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.24
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.healthsprint.com/NewUserRegistration"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<NewUserRegistration xmlns="http://www.healthsprint.com">
  <loginId>string</loginId>
  <Password>string</Password>
</NewUserRegistration>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and this is the response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<NewUserRegistrationResponse xmlns="http://www.healthsprint.com">
  <NewUserRegistrationResult>int</NewUserRegistrationResult>
</NewUserRegistrationResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and this is my code

```
$("#signup_btn").click(function (event) {

var fornewUrl = "http://192.168.1.24/REMEDIFINDERSERVICES/HSWebService.asmx?op=NewUserRegistration";


var newforsoapRequest =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" \
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" \
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
<soap:Body> \
<NewUserRegistration xmlns="http://www.healthsprint.com"> \
  <loginId>' + $(".user").val() + '</loginId> \
  <Password>' + $(".pwd").val() + '</Password> \
 </NewUserRegistration> \
 </soap:Body> \
 </soap:Envelope>';


 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: fornewUrl,
                contentType: "text/xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: newforsoapRequest,
                success: newprocessSuccess,
                error: newprocessError
            });

            function newprocessSuccess(data, status, req) {
        if (status == "success")
            $(".u_name").text($(req.responseXML).find("loginId").text());

    }

    function newprocessError(data, status, req) {
        alert(req.responseText + " " + status);
    }   

        });
```

i need to send the data to login id and password and need to display login id to other page but somehow its not working here.

Even how i will check that data has sent to web service or not

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question fully but SOAP is XML. I suppose you could use an [XML Parser](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to identify the respective XML element and use it further.

Hope I helped!

Comment: how could i check this, in my database there are three return value 0, 1, 2 0=duplicate, 1= successful, 2= unknown